# Snapshot and details bar missing in Virtual Box

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

Virtual box top big buttons for setting and creating new machine are missing

and also Snapshot and details bar missing

Any idea how can i get them back

Virtual Box on my device

[image: Virtual Box on my device]

Normal virtual box

[image: Normal virtual box]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved my problem
All virtual box processes should be closed.

open ~/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml using editor

locate
`<ExtraDataItem name="GUI/Toolbar" value="false"/>`

change it to 
`<ExtraDataItem name="GUI/Toolbar" value="true"/>`

this topic helped me
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=44283#p199315